# Update position mysql in drag and drop sortable

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a drag and drop code that change position of a list (in the screen), but I can not update the new position in MySQL

```
<div class="cf nestable-lists">
  <div class="dd" id="nestable">
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="13">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 13</div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="14">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 14</div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="15">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 15</div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I grab the "data-id" with the new position and update all in MySQL?

Comment: I tried a lots os solutions, but I don't understand de integration of jquery or javascript and php mysql.

For example, de Jquery UI touche Pubch is very nice, but I don't know where or how I put de php script to update de mysql database.

The code above, I taken from jquery.nestable

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using nestable plugin. If you are, your nestable init code should be something as:

```
$('#menu_nestable').nestable({
    group: 1, maxDepth: 3
}).on('change', updateOutput);;
```

That 'updateOutput' is a method to update something you desire. For example:

```
var updateOutput = function(e){
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');
    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));
    } else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};
```

As you can see, I can call my updateOutput whenever I want, with this line:

```
updateOutput($('#menu_nestable').data('output', $('#menu_output')));
```

This will create a JSON string and it will update in the element with the #menu_output id. In my case, it's this one:

```
<input type='hidden' name="menu_order" id="menu_output"></input>
```

You should now send this to your PHP file and work with it there. In my case, on my PHP file, what I do is every time I send the form, or every time I connect to my PHP through AJAX, I either delete the old entries in the database and include the new ones, or I change them one by one with the new values.

Such as that my fist entry of the new JSON file, will go into the first position in the database, replacing it completely, and keeping only it's ID.

If you need more help, answer here.
**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that the updateOutput method is automatically called every time you drag and drop an item, even if it's in the same place. If you want to have the new order saved in the database every time you drag and drop something, you should include an AJAX connection in your updateOutput method, connection to your database and sending the value of the #menu_output.

Comment: Thank You

I need to replace de data.

What you mean is the new position is "name" and de "id" is the some? But how and where I can do the instrutions to update mysql. It's in the some page?

Comment: You cannot simply remove those entries from the database and add new ones? Meaning, delete the bad ordered, and add the correctly ordered? And do you need to do this every time you drag and drop, or when you click "send form" or "finish" button?

Comment: Thank You I need to replace de data. What you mean is the new position is "name" and de "id" is the some? But how and where I can do the instrutions to update mysql. It's in the some page?

Comment: I can have a "send form", maybe it's more easy?

Comment: Yes, it is better to drag and drop, do everything you must do, and only when you send the form will it update the data base. In this case, what you must do is put the <input> I created there in the form, and in your PHP file, where you put info into the database, you read that, and you put it there too.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.

What you says is to create a form, and in every line (that comes from mysql) I put the <input> you created, and the when the send button is pushed the "post" will do the rest? As normali does in php mysql update?

Comment: I'ts okey, I can understand. 
No, I mean that you write that <input> in the form elements. When you "submit" the form, the values inside "menu_order" will go to the POST. Then, in the post, you must write code to read them (because they will be a JSON line) and insert them into the database.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don´t know how to work with json files, can you give me a help?